# Unusual Constraint error while Importing Oracle 9i database into Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, constraints, dump

I am carrying out an import of an Oracle 9i Database into Oracle 11g.This is a routine operation that I carry out all the time and the import always terminates successfully without warnings.

In my last operation, I encountered an unusual error which siad "Ora-02298 : Cannot validate the constraint as the parent key was not found".

There is no reason this should happen as it is a regular full import and other imports  from the same dump complete successfullt. Kindly help

Comment: Have you checked that all your target objects (indexes, tables, constraints, etc.) are valid?  Don't know otherwise.

Comment: The error is very clear, and the cause doesn't seem to be difficult to guess, but clearly you do not want to hear that there is a problem with the data itself. What sort of other answer are you hoping for?

Comment: Is the constraint in question valid/enabled on the source database?  I'm not a DBA - is it possible that some tables are being imported out of order?  Is this a warning (i.e. the restore proceeds) or is it an error that terminates the import?  What kinda constraint are we talkin' 'bout here (I'm guessing foreign key)?

Comment: Was the export done with `consistent=Y`? If not you could have had a parent/child pair inserted in the source DB during the export, between the parent and child tables being exported. (Not sure if that's what David is allusing too?) The 'other imports from the same dump' is confusing though - do you mean previous imports from the same dump *file*, or following the same export/import process?

Comment: Thank You for your replies.All my target objects are valid and there can't be a problem with the data since this is an export from a production database.

Comment: By 'other imports from the same dump' I meant 15-20 import operations have been successfully completed using the same dump file. It is an issue of a different character set on the other machine I guess. Will keep you posted as I confirm though. Thanks again